# Compute sum of series

Tags: matlab, for-loop, iteration, vectorization, series

[image]

I need to compute the sum of this series

I need the output this way:

```
If n = 3;

x = function_name(n)
```

I need to get **`x = 11.`**

```
If n = 5;

x = function_name(n)
```

I need to get **`x = 45`**.

I believe I need a for-loop to iterate; but am finding it difficult to iterate the increment value itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inc=2;
sum=1;
next=1;

n=input('what is n?\n');

for i=2:n
    next=next+inc;
    sum=sum+next;
    inc=inc+2;
end

disp('sum is ');
disp(sum);
```

Comment: I figured another way too.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want the [**`sum`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) of the [**`cumsum`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) of the differences `d` of the numbers:

```
d = 2;
n = 5;

s  =  d:d:d*(n-1)
cs  = cumsum( [1 s] )
scs = sum(cs)

%// or as anonymous function

scsh = @(n,d) sum( cumsum( [1 d:d:d*(n-1)] ) )
```

---

```
scs =

    45

scsh(5,2) =

    45
```

No need for a loop!

Comment: I need the sum (only) of the numbers in column 2 of the diagram, i.e. Series

Comment: If n = 5;  I need to have   1  + 3  +  7  +  13   +  21   = 45;   the Matlab function can take only one input; and that is n.

Comment: If I provide the input as n= 3, then Matlab needs to fetch me 11 as output; I need to develop the series inside the function, and then generate the sum

Comment: the last column (Difference between numbers in series) in the diagram is only for the coding purpose

Comment: Thanks very much; I think it works;  but is there a solution you can provide using for-loop, and may be with while.loop too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion in the first series; I have now added a new series. Will you be able to help with this one too ?  I am okay in using cumsum function, but it will be great if you could provide me some looping solution also.

Comment: Thanks very much; can you give me an idea don how to solve the 2nd problem, the new diagram in this post. ?

Comment: @user3812887 I won't help you further, sorry. Obviously these are all homework questions. I provided a good solution for your question, you are asking for a worse solution, because it's a homework question. So show at least what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Total = abc(n)

nth_term=1;
Total = 1 ;   


    for  d = 2:2:(2*(n-1))
         nth_term = nth_term + d;       
         Total =Total + nth_term;    

    end

end
```

Comment: This also works; anyway thanks to both of you guys,especially @netizen