# Matlab: Compute sum of series with increment

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, while-loop, series

[image]

I need the output this way:

```
If n = 3;
x = function_name(n)
```

**I need to get `x = 15`.**

```
If n = 5;
x = function_name(n)
```

**I need to get `x = 57`.**

I believe I need a for-loop to iterate; but am finding it difficult to iterate the increment value itself (increase the increment value by 4 for every 2 set of numbers in the series, after 1).

Comment: Have a Look at 'cumsum'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inc=4;
sum=1;
next=1;

n=input('what is n?\n');

while n~=1
      for j=1:2
          next=next+inc;
          sum=sum+next;
      end
      inc=inc+4;
      n=n-2;
end

disp('sum is ');
disp(sum);
```

Comment: thanks for the help; I have added another file you can see;  so the increments are  4,4,8,8,12,12;  so I believe in this case immediately after the nested for-loop, we need to have inc = inc+4 (instead of inc = inc*2); please let me know whether I am right

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. You are right. I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks very much; I have another similar series; I need to compute a similar sum using loops (if you see this link). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958009/compute-sum-of-series        I do not want to use any function like cumsum; can you kindly have a look at this too ?  The first series in the link provided.

Comment: Ok. I solved it too. Please dont forget to check acceptance of my answers.

Comment: Thanks very much. Appreciate your favor.

Comment: thanks so much again for your time; this series is a fairly challenging one, and am grateful that you helped me solve this.